# How to get the pid of a opened Terminal window in MacOS?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, grep, applescript

### Background

I want to obtain the `pid` of a specific Terminal window.

```
ps -A | grep -w Terminal.app | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
```

However, the above grabs the `pid` of the entire application and not of a specific tab or window that is running.

In Linux, one could execute the following:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "cd $HOME ; sleep 10"

ps ax | \
    grep -v "grep" | \
    grep "sh -c" | grep "cd $HOME ; sleep 10" \
    xargs | \
    cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

### Issue

Given the below `terminal` bash command, which opens a new terminal window and closes it much like `x-terminal-emulator` does.

**How would I attempt to grab the `pid` of the window opened via the `terminal` command using `ps` like in the Linux example?**

`terminal`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Open new terminal window from the command line using v3 syntax for applescript as needed in terminal Version 3+
# This script blocks until the cmd is executed in the new terminal window then closes the new terminal window.
#
# Usage:
#     terminal                   Opens the current directory in a new terminal window
#     terminal [PATH]            Open PATH in a new terminal window
#     terminal [CMD]             Open a new terminal window and execute CMD
#     terminal [PATH] [CMD]      Opens a new terminal window @ the PATH and executes CMD
#
# Example:
#     terminal ~/Code/HelloWorld ./setup.sh
#

# Mac OS only
[ "$(uname -s)" != "Darwin" ] && {
    echo 'Mac OS Only'
    return
}

function terminal() {
    local cmd=""
    local wd="$PWD"
    local args="$*"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        wd="$1"
        args="${*:2}"
    fi

    if [ -n "$args" ]; then
        cmd="$args"
    fi

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

osascript <<-EOF
tell application "Terminal" to tell the front window
    set w to do script "cd $wd; $cmd"
    repeat
        delay 1
        if not busy of w then exit repeat
    end repeat
    close it
end tell
EOF
}

terminal "$@"
```

Comment: `echo $$` seems to return the tab/window pid for me on Mojave.  See [How does a Linux/Unix Bash script know its own PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493642/how-does-a-linux-unix-bash-script-know-its-own-pid?rq=1)

Comment: @lx07 True, but that requires you to be in the context of the window in question. If I use `ps` for example, like the Linux example I provided, then I am able to obtain it from outside of the window.

Comment: Depending what you wish to do, you might find the value of `w` in your AppleScript to be useful.  The window that is created by `do script` returns an AppleScript reference to it (that you have assigned to `w`), which will be of the form `tab 1 of window id <number>`, where `<number>` is a five-or-so digit `id` number that remains fixed throughout the lifespan of the window.  You have to ignore the fact that the reference always contains `tab 1 of...`, which is misleading since three tabs contained in a single window will all be `tab 1 of...` three distinct `id` numbers.

Comment: If your script is `terminal.sh` and you invoke it with `./terminal.sh "cd $HOME ;  sleep 1000"` you can get the pid of the window it opens (from elsewhere) with `ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v ./terminal.sh | grep 'sleep 1000' | awk '{print $1}'`.  (Not `grep "cd $HOME ; sleep 1000"` as in your example as `ps` only shows last command passed to *terminal.sh*). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @lx07 Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoking your *terminal.sh* script using `./terminal.sh "cd $HOME ;  sleep 1000"` you can get the PID of the window opened which is running the `sleep` command using this:

```
ps ax | \
    grep 'sleep 1000' | \
    grep -v grep | \
    grep -v ./terminal.sh | \    
    awk '{print $1}'
```

If you try `ps ax | grep 'sleep 1000'` (or whatever command *terminal.sh* is running) you will see 3 returned:

```
A1398%  ps ax | grep 'sleep 1000'
 8263 s000  S+     0:00.01 /bin/bash ./terminal.sh cd /Users/XXXX ;  sleep 1000
 8272 s004  R+     0:00.00 grep sleep 1000
 8270 s005  S+     0:00.00 sleep 1000
```

The first is the command running in the window where *terminal.sh* is running, the second is the current window running `ps ax | grep 'sleep 1000'` and the last is the window actually opened by the *terminal.sh* command.

To get your windows PID therefore additionally exclude `grep` and `terminal.sh`

---

In the picture below:

1. iTerm window showing `ps ax | grep s00` before calling *terminal.sh*
2. iTerm window running `./terminal.sh "cd $HOME ;  sleep 1000"`
3. Terminal window opened by `terminal.sh` if none already open.
4. Terminal window opened by `terminal.sh` running `sleep` or whatever the passed command.
5. iTerm window run showing `ps ax | grep s00` after.  `ps ax | grep 'sleep 1000' | grep -v  grep | grep -v terminal.sh | awk '{print $1}'` shows window 4.

[image: Screenshot]

Note that your *terminal.sh* command will open an extra terminal window (3) if none are already open.  This window is *not* closed again on completion by the script although window (4) is.

Comment: That's a lot of `grep`-ing.  It would probably be simpler, quicker, and more reliable to obtain add a `ppid` column next to the `pid` for each process.  That allows you to see which `pid` spawned each child.  Also, since we know there is definitely going to be a controlling terminal running the program, the `x` flag is giving you a lot of the gaff you then work so hard to `grep` out.  The `a` flag is unlikely to be needed either.

Answer (score 2):

Use `echo $$`. Mac OS is a unixy box and so $$ is an alias for myPid.

As you can see I am first showing all the shells (I use zsh) running at the moment. Below that you can see that `echo $$` shows the PID of the pre-existing shell and not something new.

`~ % ps aux | grep zsh
ram              30724   0.8  0.0  4869828   5888 s003  S     9:28AM   0:00.35 -zsh
ram              29765   0.0  0.0  4868884      8 s002  S+    5:12PM   0:00.40 -zsh
ram              29654   0.0  0.0  5028628      8 s001  S+    4:52PM   0:00.49 -zsh
ram               8001   0.0  0.0  4793028      8 s000  S+   13Jan20   0:00.70 -zsh
ram              30782   0.0  0.0  4258888    200 s003  R+    9:29AM   0:00.00 egrep --color=auto zsh`

`~ % echo $$
30724
~ %`

Comment: Doesn't work in this case unfortunately.  As the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) states *"($$) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.*" and indeed here `$$` gives the pid of the calling process not the opened window.